# Middleware req.body em form-data

Tags: node.js, express.js, postman

Estou tentando adicionar um middleware para validação simples de formulário, ele funciona bem quando mando a requisição como raw no postman, mas quando mudo para form-data (para envio de imagens) o console.log(req.body) (3 linha) retorna "{}", de qual modo posso receber os dados da requisição nesse caso?

Middleware:

```
const petValidation = (req, res, next)=>{
 
    console.log(req.body)
 
    const { name, age, weight, color } = req.body
 
    console.log(name)
 
    if(!name){
        res.status(422).json({ message : "O nome é obrigatório!"})
        return
    }
    if(!age){
        res.status(422).json({ message : "A idade é obrigatória!"})
        return
    }
    if(!weight){
        res.status(422).json({ message : "O peso é obrigatório!"})
        return
    }
    if(!color){
        res.status(422).json({ message : "A cor é obrigatória!"})
        return
    }
 
    next()
}
 
module.exports = petValidation
```

Rota:

```
const express = require('express')
const PetContoller = require('../controllers/PetController')
 
const router = express.Router()
 
// middlewares
 
const verifyToken = require('../helpers/verify-token')
const petValidation = require('../helpers/pet-validation')
const { imageUpload } = require('../helpers/image-upload')
 
 
 
router.post('/create', verifyToken, petValidation, imageUpload.array('images'), PetContoller.create)
 
 
module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloca o imageUpload.array('images'... antes do petValidation.

Senão der certo, coloca aqui seu arquivo inicial do servidor (geralmente chamado de "server.ts"/"index.ts"

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).